# Is my proof right? (Product of the groups related with isomorphism)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$Q)$ There are three multiplicative groups $G, H$ and $K$. Let the group homomorphsims $f : G \to H$ and  $g : H \to K$.

Say $g \circ f : G \to K $ be a group ismorphism.

Suppose $f(G) \lhd H$, then show $H \simeq f(G) \times \ker$ $g$

---

Despite of there is no solution for this question in my book, I tried to prove the above my self. Here is my attempt. I'll put the identities of the each group $G$, $H$ and $K $ by  $e_G, e_H$ and $e_K$ respectively.

$pf)$  $(1)$  $f(G) \lhd H$,  $kerg \lhd H$ Hence, $f(G) \ker g \leq H$

$(2)$ Show $f(G) \cap \ker g = \{e_H\}$

Suppose $f(G) \cap \ker g \neq \{e_H\}$, So $\exists$ $h(\neq e_H)$ $s.t.$ $h \in (f(G) \cap \ker g)$

Since $h \in f(G) $, $\exists$ $g(\neq e_G)$ $s.t.$ $f(g) =h$.  then because of the $ h \in \ker g$, so $g \circ f(g) =g(h)=e_K $. It is contradict with the fact that $g \circ f$ is a isomorhpism.

$(3)$ Show $\vert f(G) \ker g \vert = \vert H \vert $

By $f(G) \cap \ker g = \{e_H\}$ and isomorphism theorem
$ \vert f(G) /  (\ker g \cap f(G)) \vert  = \vert K \vert$, we can conclude $\vert f(G) \vert = \vert K \vert $

Plus $H/\ker g \simeq K$ Hence, $\vert H \vert = \vert K \vert \vert \ker g \vert = \vert f(G) \vert\vert 
\ker g \vert$

Final conclusion is $H = f(G)\ker g \simeq f(G) \times \ker g$ by $(1)$~$(3)$

Is my proof right? Any advice or comment always welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is OK provided the groups are finite. But they may not be, so you have to find another argument for (3) - it's not difficult.

Comment: @ancientmathematician,  Err...  I missed the the case infinite. :( Thanks for your advice.